# Rails button disappearing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 buttons. 3 of which are hidden until one button is pressed. The issue is i've placed the buttons in a div class. Which forces the buttons below the first button. (see below)

I'm wanting to have the buttons in line, (hopefully disabled if possible after being clicked but that could be for another day) Rather than having the buttons under each other

**Diagram Time!**

Buttons are currently like this

```
-
- - -
```

i'd like them to be like

```
- - - -
```

Currently there in the div tag for the ID because the ID is linked elsewhere

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 20px">

  <%= link_to 'Comm invoiced out Venue', admin_conference_statuses_path(conference_id: @conference.id), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :post, remote: true %>

  <div id="conf_status_buttons">
    <% if @conference.conference_status %>
        <%= link_to 'Cross charged to Client', admin_conference_status_path(id: @conference.conference_status, status_name: 'cross_charged_use'), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :put, remote: true %>
        <%= link_to 'Payment received Commission', admin_conference_status_path(id: @conference.conference_status, status_name: 'payment_received_comm'), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :put, remote: true %>
        <%= link_to 'Payment Received', admin_conference_status_path(id: @conference.conference_status, status_name: 'payment_received'), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :put, remote: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your styling is off, try this in your css

```
#conf_status_buttons {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Close, the button that was at the front is now at the back haha!

Comment: That will be because the bootstrap "btn" class already has `float:left;` set. But it has changed the order in which your buttons display?

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking something like a div id="btn"
And in this div you have the button and on action you run a script that changes id="btn" to all the buttons.
This will place them in line.

I think.

I'm currently typing from phone, so it's hard to write exactly how I mean.

Edit: my tags was hidden on forum